# Custom field to be set as default filter while opening a sales order grid page in magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]Can't get the data collection for sales order grid, I have to add filter and show the sales order grid in admin grid page in magento-2

Comment: here is the collection class name \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Grid\Collection

Please modify your question with more details what column you want to show etc.

Comment: I have custom filter and added into sales order admin grid, i need to set that custom filter while loading the sales order admin grid page for particular admin user